# Strange C++ matrix multiplication/initialization

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm using Cygwin, Windows Vista, Norton anti-virus (someone asked me about this before). I previously asked a question about strange C++ behavior that no one could answer. Here's another. Simple matrix multiplication exercise. This form below gives strange (and wrong) results:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int A[3][3]={{1,5,0},{7,1,2},{0,0,1}};
   int B[3][3]={{-2,0,1},{1,0,0},{4,1,0}};
   int D[3][3];
   for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
      for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
      {
         for (int k=0;k<3;k++)
         {
            D[i][j]+=A[i][k]*B[k][j];

         }
      }
   }

   for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
      for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
      {
         cout<<D[i][j]<<"\n";
      }}
   return 0;
}
```

BUT a very small change gives correct results: (all I've done is move the initialized matrices outside main()  ).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int A[3][3]={{1,5,0},{7,1,2},{0,0,1}};
int B[3][3]={{-2,0,1},{1,0,0},{4,1,0}};
int D[3][3];

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
      for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
      {
         for (int k=0;k<3;k++)
         {
            D[i][j]+=A[i][k]*B[k][j];

         }
      }
   }

   for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
      for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
      {
         cout<<D[i][j]<<"\n";
      }}
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are "strange (and wrong) results"?  What are "correct results"?

Comment: I agree. And the wrong results were very big numbers, the correct results more "reasonable" numbers I didn't care to wish. Regardless the issue was answered below.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to initialize the array `D` to 0 in  your first case. This is automatically done when the array is global, but not when it is local (simplified, but explains the behavior).

Comment: Thank you for this. How does C++ choose ridiculous numbers like: -2144138944
1
-13216
0
-2144138944
1
-12816
  etc. to initialize D to in the latter case?

Comment: If left uninitialized, the value will be whatever happened to be in that memory spot last.

Comment: @Nights C++ does not chose the values at all. Technically, reading an uninitialized variable is [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), anything may happen. In reality, you will either see whatever happens to be there atm  or some debug value set by the compiler (e.g. MSVC sets uninitialized bytes to `0xCC` in debug builds) interpreted as your data type.